# Installing odoo in ubuntu raises error when creating db user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/02_setup.html) to install Odoo on Ubuntu, but I get this error with command `sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER`:

```
could not change directory to "/home/hugolvc/Documents/Code/odoo/odoo": Permission denied
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The 'postgres' user doesn't have access to your current work directory, try `sudo -iu postgres createuser -s $USER` to run the command in a login shell as the user 'postgres' and the message should not appear, since the working directory will then be postgres's home directory.

Afterwards check with `sudo -iu postgres psql -c 'SELECT * FROM pg_user'` whether the creation of the user was successful.

Comment: I got this error: `sudo: you may not specify both the -i and -s options`

Comment: I've forgot the createuser in my command, try this `sudo -iu postgres createuser -s $USER`